# Unable to start firefox using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

If I run testcases using cron job I am getting this issue, if I manually run the same in eclipse it works fine.The selenium version is 2.44.

> Unable to bind to locking port 7055 within 45000 ms Build info:
>   version: '2.43.0', revision: '597b76b', time: '2014-09-09 20:52:38'
>   System info: host: 'sp-anjani-desktop', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name:
>   'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.13.0-39-generic',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_65' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Comment: Similar case: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5172

Comment: But the same setup I can run manually, using ant "target". So how come it is only failing when I run it as cron.

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium server  : 2.44 jar file
firefox : 35.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Use 2.53 or 2.51 Jar files with firefox version 45.0 it works smoothly